# obtener la cadena limpia, sólo con dígitos, sin signos, de un JFormattedTextField en Java

Tags: java, regex

Uso MaskFormatter con JFormattedTextField para dos campos, en el cual solicito números de teléfono.

Foto:

[image: 2 campos con (___)___-____]

Luego, tengo un botón llamado "Calcular", en donde tengo lo siguiente para validar que los campos no estén vacíos:

```
if(validarCampos(txtNumeroDeOrigen, txtNumeroDeDestino, txtDuracion)) {
}
```

Entonces, tengo esta función para hacer las validaciones:

```
public boolean validarCampos(JFormattedTextField txtNumeroDeOrigen, JFormattedTextField txtNumeroDeDestino, JTextField txtDuracion)
{
    if(txtNumeroDeOrigen.getText().replaceAll("[()-_]", "").trim().length() == 0
        && txtNumeroDeDestino.getText().replaceAll("[()-_]", "").trim().length() == 0
        && txtDuracion.getText().isEmpty())
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Debe agregar un numero de origen.\nDebe agregar un numero de destino.\nDebe agregar la duracion.");
        return true;
    }

    else if(txtNumeroDeOrigen.getText().replaceAll("[()-_]", "").trim().length() == 0
            && txtNumeroDeDestino.getText().replaceAll("[()-_]", "").trim().length() == 0)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Debe agregar un numero de origen.\nDebe agregar un numero de destino.");
        return true;
    }
}
```

He usado lo siguiente para saber si el campo JFormattedTextField  esta vacío:

```
.getText().replaceAll("[()-_]", "").trim().length() == 0
```

Pero por alguna razón no me funciona, me sigue diciendo que los campos están vacíos cuando en realidad ya tienen números.

Foto del problema presente:

[image: Campos completados que aún muestran el mensaje de error]

¿No es la forma correcta de validar un MaskFormatter? ¿Cuál es?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Una forma sería , Reemplazando todo lo que no es número mediante el método [replaceAll(String regex, String reemplazo)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) para luego acceder al `Length` y verificar si es **0**

```
if(textField.getText().replaceAll("\\D+", "").length()==0)
        System.out.println("Vacío");
        /* ("\\D+") para reemplazar lo que no sea un número */
```

La función para validar sería así:

```
public boolean validarCampos(JFormattedTextField txtNumeroDeOrigen,
       JFormattedTextField txtNumeroDeDestino, JTextField txtDuracion)
{
  return (txtNumeroDeOrigen.getText().replaceAll("\\D+", "").length()==0 ||
          txtNumeroDeDestino.getText().replaceAll("\\D+", "").length()==0 ||
          txtDuracion.getText().isEmpty());
 }
```

Para en tu `if` llamar a dicho método ,y ahí lanzar el Mensaje correspondiente

```
if(!validarCampos(textField, textField2, txtn)){
        /* Lógica luego de validar que no están vacíos */
}
else
 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Debe agregar un numero de origen.
   \n Debe agregar un numero de destino.\n Debe agregar la duracion.");
```

Comment: entiendo pero, esto no hace lo mismo: .getText().replaceAll("[()-_]", "").trim().length() == 0, ?, en mi caso no me funciona.

Comment: Hola, funciona perfecto pero, no entendí la lógica. Podrías explicarme esta línea por favor: .getText().replaceAll("\\D+", "").length()==0, cómo es que funciona y la que yo tenía nó?. Tenía entendido que había que usar .trim(), la verdad estoy sorprendido.